# Resolving ids to a service in a service oriented architecture

Tags: microservices

Given a service oriented architecture, for example in a blog system let's say we have services for User, Post, and Comments.

A new requirement comes that a User should be able to "Like" any other entity, and any future entity. A user can thumbs up another user, post, or comment.

A new "Likes" service is introduced to store this data. A client may provide a user id and entity id to the new service, which is stored in its own data store.

Now we want to get all of the likes of a user, and the entity id isn't useful on its own, so we want to fetch some data about it. But we don't know from the id alone which service to fetch the additional data from.

A simple solution would be to just store the type of the entity alongside its id, but I want to make sure I'm not missing something

Comment: Yes a type of for example field: entityName makes sense here as the combination with entityId allows a full identification of the object. The microservice may also cache for example the name + photo url if you want so the service can produce a list of liked entities on it's own. This depends on how you architecture your microservices (many flavors possible in practice).